# Log file monitoring using active agent in zabbix?

Tags: monitoring, zabbix, log-files

I am trying to do log file monitoring using active agents in zabbix.

Have created the below trigger
log[/var/log/syslog,error]
log[/var/log/zabbix/zabbix_agentd.log,error]

But, no data is being fetched when i see the latest data tab. 
Below error is shown in the log file:-

active check configuration update from [server ip] started to fail (cannot connect to [[server ip]: [4] Interrupted system call)

Any help on this.

Comment: The error message seems to be self-explanatory - agent us unable to connect to the Zabbix server.

Comment: the configurations are fine and it connects when in passive mode. only gives this error when ServerActive is enabled.

Comment: You might want to read on how active/passive modes operate in Zabbix.